# Windows UWP Application - Time duration for AUTO expire from the store

Tags: windows, uwp, microsoft-partner-center

We have Windows UWP application in Windows store and we are planning to withdrawn in near future. I have query about this Windows app auto expiration.

I have checked in Windows Store submission process and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/publish-your-app/overview?pivots=store-installer-msix) and could not find the any related information.

Our queries.

1. How long the app will be available at store If no new version upload in store? Is there any expire time period for app?
2. Does the app auto expire based on any certification expiration?

Comment: Have you checked my reply about your question?

Answer (score 0):

> How long the app will be available at store If no new version upload
> in store? Is there any expire time period for app?

There is no expire time period for app.

> Does the app auto expire based on any certification expiration?

When the certificate of your app expires, the store will automatically renew it, which means your app has no expiry date.

If you want to withdraw in near future, please make your product available in Partner Center.